# Binding object collection based on the value of a property

Tags: c#, linq, telerik

I am trying to bind a object collection to a Telerik TreeView control. My object structure would somehow look like:

```
Item 1.1
   - Item 1.1.1
       - Item 1.2.1
       - Item 1.2.2
   - Item 1.1.2
...
Item n.1
   - Item n.1.1
      - Item n.2.1
        - Item n.3.1
```

All these object have a common bool property, i.e. isBindable. I want to bind this collection to my TreeView control, but the control should only bind the object if its property isBindable = true.

I don't want to loop through the whole collection and remove one-by-one based on isBindable before doing an ItemSource to the control.

Any better idea how can I achieve that, maybe with LINQ?

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Comment: Why not bind the tree view to YourCollection.Select(item => item.IsBindable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to achieve this using recursion. You would need a single `foreach` loop though. Please see the below method. Just pass your collection to this method and see if it gets filtered.

```
private List<Item> Filter(List<Item> itemList)
        {

            List<Item> filteredItems = (from c in itemList
                                        where c.IsBindable == true
                                        select c).ToList();
            foreach (Item item in filteredItems)
            {
                if (item.Item != null)
                    item.Item = Filter(item.Item);
            }

            return filteredItems;
        }

class Item
    {
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
        public bool IsBindable { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
            IsBindable = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more what I am looking for (even though it used a foreach)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your items using `Where`:

```
collection.Where(x => x.isBindable);
```

Comment: can I apply that with the Tree-like object collection, like I mentioned in the post. I can do with a simple object collection, i.e. List<myobj>, but my obj structure is like a tree, i.e. each object in the main collection has a List<object2> and each object2 has a list<object3>, i.e. tree-like structure

Comment: @Bhaskar: Sorry, I don't know Telerik controls. But I imagine it should be something like: `treeView.ItemSource = collection.Where(x => x.isBindable);`. How do you bind your collection for now?

Comment: i simply bind the collection same way, i.e. treeView.ItemSource = collection. But my question is, using collection.Where(x => x.isBindable) will only filter the top level object, what about its child object collections, i can have n level depth of objects collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can get make a tree into a linear sequence and check your condition like this

```
collection.SelectMany(item=> item.SubItems).Where(subitem)
```